# I want to send specific link inside notifications send through firebase push notification,how to do it?

Tags: android, firebase

Suppose in my notification,Today is X's birthday it opens FB link of X on clicking the notification and same for Y, How to do it using firebase

Answer (score 9):

Below is the way to do that:

1) server site make request with:

Request URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Method: POST

Header:

- Content-Type: application/json
- Authorization: key=...your_key...

Body:

```
{
  "registration_ids" :[devices_token],
  "priority" : "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "Notification body here",
    "title" : "notification title here",
    "click_action": "action.open.facebook.with.url"
  },
  "data" : {
    "openURL" : "https://facebook.com/xxx"
  }
}
```

2) Android app:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.OpenFacebookLink">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="action.open.facebook.with.url" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In your subclass of `FirebaseMessagingService`:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
    super.onMessageReceived(message);
    String url = message.getData().get("openURL");
    if(message.getNotification()!=null) {
        // do some thing with url when app in foreground
    } else {
        // do some thing with url when app in background
    }
}
```

In your `OpenFacebookLink` activity let do that:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String url = intent.getStringExtra("openURL");
// do open facebook with url
```

Comment: does that mean when click the notification bar, it will open the app and then open the url?

Comment: what about the javascript? because click_action not working in javascript web notification

Comment: @ Rameshwar Patnaik  follow the document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#web-v8 . You must place link under webpush instead of data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the notification manually from FCM panel then:
then make a key like:
**link** and put the **value** i.e. your fb link. Then send the notification to that particular user or a topic or a segment from FCM panel.

You can handle it inside your application like:

Extract the data from notification then...

```
if (data != null) {
            directLink = data.optString("directLink");
        }
```

Inside the notification open method:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(link));
            browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But if you want to make this process automated then you'll have to write a script that will extract the birthday links from some database and send notifications to users via **FCM API** and do a post request on that API.